# Appcelerator - How to change tab button style?

Tags: javascript, ios, titanium, appcelerator

I'm working on Titanium and developing for iOS and I want to know if there's a way to change the style of the tab button in a tab. I want to make it look flat and with a different backgroundColor and remove the gradient it has.

I've tried the following:

```
var tab2 = Titanium.UI.createTab({

       title:'Members',
       window:peopleInGroup,
       backgroundColor : '#0f0',
       backgroundSelectedColor : '#0f0',
       backgroundFocusedColor : '#0f0'

});
```

But the backgroundColor didn't change. Also the text in the tab is aligned to the bottom but I want it to be in the center of the button. How can I change the style for the tab button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Appcelerator Titanium have no any method for change "TAB" BackgroundColor Change Yet.

This have only BackgroundImage Change and Image Change,

You can try custom Tab creation for Changing Color like [this](https://gist.github.com/853935).

Answer (score 0):

As of SDK version 3, [`Titanium.UI.TabGroup`](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TabGroup-property-activeTabBackgroundSelectedColor) has a `tabsBackgroundColor` property which sets the default background color for inactive tabs. This is supported on all platforms (iOS, Android, mobile-web, etc...)